# How to stop an event if not triggered directly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

Lets say there is a `textbox` and a `button`. On the click of button a function is executed, and on the `focusout` of textbox, the button is clicked. What I wanna know is, is there a way, I can determine that weather the user `clicked` the button, *or* it was triggered by `focusout` event of `textbox`, so that I may do some custom work *in* the `click` event, *if* it was triggered by `focusout` of textbox?

I could write some code, but I don't even have any idea where to begin with, I know the jQuery `event` and `event.which` property, but I wonder if it/they could be useful in this situation?

Comment: Try to set a flag when focusout occurs and use it to distinguish between the two events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on how you're triggering the function from the `textarea` `blur` event, if you're simply triggering the `click` event using the following approach:

```
$('#btn').click(
    function(e){
        buttonActivation(e);
    });

$('#txt').blur(
    function(e){
        $('#btn').click();
    });
```

Then I'd suggest evaluating the `originalEvent` object to see what the original event was (if there was no `originalEvent` then the function was called by a programmatic `click` event, with jQuery; whereas if the `originalEvent.type` evaluates to `click` then the button must have been clicked.

```
function buttonActivation(e) {
    if (!e) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var oEvent = e.originalEvent;
        if (oEvent === undefined) {
            console.log('Programmatic event');
        }
        else if (oEvent.type == 'click') {
            console.log('User-initiated event');
        }
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/CSej9/).

If, however, you're using something like the following (simply calling the same function from a different place):

```
$('#btn').click(
    function(e){
        buttonActivation(e);
    });

$('#txt').blur(
    function(e){
        buttonActivation(e);
    });
```

Then I'd recommend either directly assessing `e.target` or `e.type`:

```
function buttonActivation(e) {
    if (!e) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var oEvent = e.type;
        if (oEvent === 'blur') {
            console.log('Programmatically-triggered event, on ' + oEvent);
        }
        else if (oEvent == 'click') {
            console.log('User-initiated ' + oEvent + ' event');
        }
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/CSej9/1/).

Answer (score 2):

you can use event.target to determine which DOM element has initiated the event, then you can check if this is the button or the textbox.

check this out for more information: http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

from the documetation:

> ```
> event.target
> ```
>
> The target property can be the element that registered for the event
>   or a descendant of it. It is often useful to compare event.target to
>   this in order to determine if the event is being handled due to event
>   bubbling. This property is very useful in event delegation, when
>   events bubble.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `event.target`. By default, jquery provides the event to the handler function.
    Here's an example : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dMq8R/1/)

Comment: If you look at just the blur event in your jsFiddle, `event.target` is the textbox on the focusout: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/dMq8R/3/.  So, how does this help solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can [**pass an additional parameters**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/Qb92X/) when triggering the event and check them in event handler.

So if you wrote

`button$.trigger('click', 'hello');`

then you can write the handler like

```
button$.on('click', function(e, someStr) {
    console.log(someStr || 'Nothing passed');
    // Obviously if someStr is undefined, the user clicked the button,
    // otherwise the $.trigger() method has been called.
});
```